# How to capture Storage.Objects.Insert request failure/errors?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Here is my code to upload file into Google cloud storage,

```
public static void uploadFile(String name, String contentType, File file, String bucketName)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(contentType, new FileInputStream(file));
    // Setting the length improves upload performance
    contentStream.setLength(file.length());
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject()
            // Set the destination object name
            .setName(name)
            // Set the access control list to publicly read-only
            .setAcl(Arrays.asList(new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")));

    // Do the insert
    Storage client = StorageFactory.getService();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);

    StorageObject response =insertRequest.execute();
    System.out.println("Storage insert response: "+response.toPrettyString());

}
```

How to capture errors out of response object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors won't exist in the response object. Instead, you'll see an exception be generated. You can `catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e)` and inspect the `GoogleJsonError` from `e.getDetails()`. See [an example](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java#L134). Other exceptions can apply, including some that never product JSON output.